# IN my custom table i want the difference of 15 days to get userids from the table. Date_diff function is not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;

    $today =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATEDIFF($today,end_date)<=15 ") as $key => $row){
     // each column in your row will be accessible like this
        echo $my_column = $row->user_id;
        echo"<br/><br/>";
    }

?>
```

I have create a function in which i want the where the user registration ending date is coming to close to 15 days so i want the value in foreach loop. I have got some success.  In my custom table i am getting value as the date in this
 format -> 2016-06-07 12:53:55 So i am printing the value $today variable in same format like to get the difference but it is printing nothing but if i remove where clause, I am able to get the values then.  I dont know what i am doing wrong here. All i want is when it comes close to the 15 days before this date like 07 june 2016 so i will get those user ids which are going to expire. Please Can you help me I will definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Quote your `$today` value, otherwise the DATEDIFF function won't recognise it as a date

Comment: And `DATEDIFF(a,b)` does `a-b` so the "bigger" = later date should be put first.

Comment: so i changed my query to this...$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATEDIFF(end_date,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))<=15 ")  but still not getting any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use curdate() as a built in function of mysql, so you dont need to worry about passing a string into the query.
2. switch datediff order to get the expected result.
3. Add a filter to remove the ones that already expired.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tablename 
> WHERE DATEDIFF(end_date,curdate())<=15 
> and end_date>=curdate()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE end_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

`NOW()` is a mysql function which return the current date and time

Comment: hey mynawaz it didnt worked ..but adrianbr answer is working. Still thanks for the help